# Convert PDF to JPG image with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg

I am using ImageMagik to try and convert the contents of a PDF to JPG, but keep getting an empty jpg. I have made sure the perms are 777  on everything for testing so I am a little lost how to continue.

Here is the script I am running

```
<?php

    exec('convert testfile.pdf output.jpg', $output, $return_var);

?>
```

Comment: You may need to specify the full path to convert. Is your input and output in the same directory as where you run convert? Check the $output variable for error messages? Does Imagemagick include delegates Ghostscript and libjpeg?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php
    $pdf = 'testfile.pdf';
    $save = 'output.jpg';

    exec('convert "'.$pdf.'" -colorspace RGB -resize 800 "'.$save.'"', $output, $return_var);

?>
```

Comment: To my recent experiences ghostScript is more faster than convert command, try this complete library I wrote which does this super fast https://github.com/imalhasaranga/PDFBox

Comment: What are the values $output, $return_var

Answer (score 1):

Use the absolute path to the binary, like this:

```
exec('/usr/bin/convert testfile.pdf output.jpg', $output, $return_var);
```

But make sure your `convert` binary is actually on `/usr/bin` you can check that out with the following command:

`which convert`

Answer (score 1):

```
convert -normalize yourfile.pdf[0] yourdestination.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick internally use GhostScript and Generally the conversion of ImageMagick is slow Comparing to Ghoastscript, so If you are only interested on getting convert pdf to images then Ghostscript `gs` command is faster. 
below is an sample wrapper around Ghostscript which I wrote few days back.

[PDFLib-Php](https://github.com/imalhasaranga/PDFLib)

```
$pdflib = new ImalH\PDFLib\PDFLib();
$pdflib->setPdfPath($pdf_file_path);
$pdflib->setOutputPath($folder_path_for_images);
$pdflib->setImageQuality(95);
$pdflib->setDPI(300);
$pdflib->setPageRange(1,$pdflib->getNumberOfPages());
$pdflib->convert();
```

Comment: No, that isn't PDFBox. The correct URL for PDFBox is https://pdfbox.apache.org/ .

Comment: what is your problem mate ? PDFBox is for java and this for php and the question is asking how to do it in php no in java

Answer (score 0):

Here you have my solution. Use Imagick directly in your php code.

Convert all PDF pages to JPG

```
 // create Imagick object
 $imagick = new Imagick();
 // Reads image from PDF
 $imagick->readImage('file.pdf');
 // Writes an image
 $imagick->writeImages('converted.jpg', false);
```

Convert specific PDF page to JPG

```
 // create Imagick object
 $imagick = new Imagick();
 // Read image from PDF
 $imagick->readImage('test.pdf[0]');
 // Writes an image
 $imagick->writeImages('converted_page_one.jpg');
```

Another way to deal with this problem is to use **spatie/pdf-to-image** library.

Cheers!

Comment: trying to convert pdf to image and got error, Imagick extension enabled , please help me

Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: UnableToOpenBlob 'sample.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3315 in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\pdf\convert\index.php:6 Stack trace: #0 E:\XAMPP\htdocs\pdf\convert\index.php(6): Imagick->readimage('sample.pdf') #1 {main} thrown in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\pdf\convert\index.php on line 6

Comment: again Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified. ' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/794 in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\pdf\convert\index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 E:\XAMPP\htdocs\pdf\convert\index.php(8): Imagick->readimage('E:/XAMPP/htdocs...') #1 {main} thrown in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\pdf\convert\index.php on line 8