# PHP exec() convert pdf to jpg with space in filename on Windows

Tags: php, windows

How to convert pdf files that contain spaces in their filenames using the exec() function.

For e.g: file 1.pdf to file 1.jpg

```
<?php

$pdf = "file 1.pdf";
$pdf_first_page = "file 1.pdf[0]";
$jpg = str_replace("pdf", "jpg", $pdf);
exec ("convert $pdf_first_page $jpg");

?>
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
convert.exe: unable to open image `file 1.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702.
convert.exe: no images defined `file 1.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3257.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PDF to JPG image with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600598/convert-pdf-to-jpg-image-with-php)

Comment: Converting the pdf file without space in the filename is working for me. I'm having problems with files that contains space in their filenames.

Comment: The linked question also offers a solution for this which is to put the filename in between quotes

Comment: Still it doesn't convert pdf files with space in their filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the arguments through [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg), like this:

```
$pdf_escaped = escapeshellarg($pdf_first_page);
$jpg_escaped = escapeshellarg($jpg);
exec("convert $pdf_escaped $jpg_escaped");
```

Comment: Still it doesn't convert pdf files with space in their filename.

Comment: It should. Could you please edit your question to specify which OS you're using PHP on (Linux, Windows?), and the specific error that you're getting? (You *are* [logging errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-to-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file), right?)

Comment: Not I'm not logging errors. I'm using PHP on windows.

Comment: convert.exe: unable to open image `file 1.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702.
convert.exe: no images defined `file 1.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3257.

Comment: Does it work if you rename the files to have no space in their name (and change your code accordingly, of course)? Looking at your error message, it looks like the spaces are working fine, but the file is not in the directory that PHP looks for it in.

Comment: Just tested with renaming 'file 1' to 'file'. It works. It is some problem with the path of the file?

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I restarted Apache and it's now good :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the arguments (filenames) in double quotes (which you have to escape by backslashes):

```
exec ("convert \"$pdf_first_page\" \"$jpg\"");
```

> To surround the passed shell comand arguments with double quotes is generally
>   a good practice - even with arguments/filenames without spaces

Comment: Still it doesn't convert pdf files with space in their filename.

Comment: Your code with the last line altered as proposed in my answer runs successfully on my machine (Debian). It outputs `file 1.jpg` as expected.

Comment: convert.exe: unable to open image `file 1.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702.
convert.exe: no images defined `file 1.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3257.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces in file names on Linux must be escaped with `\` note escape character before the space. Below is an example.

```
file\ 1.pdf
```