# how to convert pdf to jpg image format

Tags: php, pdf

Code is written below.The output come with the images converted sucessfully but not foound on images.
It converted successfully,but the image was not generated properly in my defined folder. Any suggestion??

```
<?php
$message = "";
$display = "";
if($_FILES)
{
    $output_dir = "uploads/";
    ini_set("display_errors",1);
    if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
    {
        $RandomNum   = time();

        $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name']));
        $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type']; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

        $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
        $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
        if($ImageExt != "pdf")
        {
            $message = "Invalid file format only <b>\"PDF\"</b> allowed.";
        }
        else
        {
            $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
            $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $NewImageName);

            $location   = "photos/";
            $name       = $output_dir. $NewImageName;
            $num = count_pages($name);
            $RandomNum   = time();
            $nameto     = $output_dir.$RandomNum.".jpg";
            $convert    = $location . " " . $name . " ".$nameto;
            exec($convert);
            for($i = 0; $i<$num;$i++)
            {
                $display .= "<img src='$output_dir$RandomNum-$i.jpg' title='Page-$i' /><br>"; 
            }
            $message = "PDF converted to JPEG sucessfully!!";
        }
    }
}
function count_pages($pdfname) {
      $pdftext = file_get_contents($pdfname);
      $num = preg_match_all("/\/Page\W/", $pdftext, $dummy);
      return $num;
    }
$content = $message.'<br />'.$display.'<br><form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
 Please choose a file: <input name="myfile" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>';


echo $content;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Install ghostscript

https://www.ghostscript.com/faq.html

on Linux apt-get install ghostscript

on RedHat/Centos yum install ghostscript

### Install ImageMagick

https://blog.runcloud.io/imagemagick/

on Linux apt-get install ImageMagick

on RedHat/Centos yum install ImageMagick

You need perl installed or you can do the geometry calculation yourself in PHP or other language.

### Conversion script

This bash script converts email_001.pdf to email_001.jpg

```
# convert possibly multi-part PDF to one or more jpegs
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -r600x600 -sOutputFile=email-%02d.jpg ./email_001.pdf
# get dimensions of the jpeg and then divide it by 4 or you get a huge combined jpg
GEOMETRY=`identify email-01.jpg | perl -ane '{@d=split "x", $F[3]; printf "%dx%d+0+0", $d[0]/4, $d[1]/4}'`
# join the jpegs together into a single jpeg
montage -tile 1 -density 200 -quality 100 -geometry $GEOMETRY ./email-*.jpg  ./email_001.jpg
# remove the intermediate jpegs
rm ./email-*.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to do a lot easier.
Create a new object from the class `Imagick()`

```
<?php
 // create Imagick object
 $imagick = new Imagick();

 // Reads image from PDF
 $imagick->readImage('myfile.pdf');

 // Writes an image or image sequence Example- converted-0.jpg, converted-1.jpg
 $imagick->writeImages('converted.jpg', false);
?>
```

Here is some example if you have a problem with an empty output: ([Origanl Post Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600650/5930557))

```
<?php
    $pdf = 'testfile.pdf';
    $save = 'output.jpg';

    exec('convert "'.$pdf.'" -colorspace RGB -resize 800 "'.$save.'"', $output, $return_var);
?>
```

**If all this does not help you. Look [here](https://arjunphp.com/convert-pdf-jpeg-php/) for detailed explanation**